# Angular7 cdkDropList between arrays with dynamic lists

Tags: angular, angular-material

I get the following error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '2' of string 'One'`
from the following datalist that I created to mimic the form that my actual data looks like, and the template view that I have seen to use from angular material documentation for dynamic lists like these. But even though they say what to do, they do not give an example..

I can not get the following to work:

Component:

```
lists = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.lists = [{number: 'One', amount: [1, 2, 3, 4]}, {number: 'Two', amount: [5, 6, 7, 8]}, {number: 'Three', amount: [9, 10, 11, 12]}];
}

drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
        moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
        transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
            event.container.data,
            event.previousIndex,
            event.currentIndex);
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="list.number" *ngFor="let list of lists" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    {{list.number}}
    <div cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="item" *ngFor="let item of list.amount">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get the actual index of your list item..
Try this:

**TS:**

```
activeNumIndex: number;
enter(i) {
    this.activeNumIndex = i;
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(this.lists[this.activeNumIndex].amount, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="list.number" *ngFor="let list of lists; let i=index;" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    {{list.number}}
    <div cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="item" *ngFor="let item of list.amount" (mouseenter)="enter(i)" style="border:1px solid black">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a duplicate in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-dragndrop?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and especially the Stackblitz example, they help so much. But could you please try and make your stackblitz example also move items between arrays. At the moment it just moves them inside an array. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to move item between arrays, you can mark each `cdkDropList` using `#mark-name` and use `cdkDropListConnectedTo` directive to connect them.

And if the number of `cdkDropList` is not known, you can use `cdkDropListGroup` directive to setup connection between the `cdkDropList` automatically.

the example would be:

```
<div cdkDropListGroup>
    <div cdkDropList *ngFor="let list of lists; let i=index;"
         [cdkDropListData]="list.number" 
         (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">{{list.number}}

           <div cdkDrag *ngFor="let item of list.amount"
                [cdkDragData]="item"  
                (mouseenter)="enter(i)" 
                style="border:1px solid black">{{item}}
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Stackblitz Example**

here is some example [code copied from angular material example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draggable-arrays?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

and with [dynamic number of list](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draggable-dynamic-arrays?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

hope it helps, cheers!